# Boost serialization : read varying type of data

Tags: c++, class, parsing, boost, boost-serialization

I have a C++ / CLI project that uses boost serialization to serialize three different classes. I would like to know if it is possible to parse the first line of the boost serialization archive in order to know what class was serialized in this archive, and then create an object of the appropriate class and deserialize the archive into the object. That line would contain an ID (maybe a int or value of an enum class) to identify which class was serialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file format is already handled by your choice of Archive implementation.

In practice that would be `boost::archive::text_oarchive`, `boost::archive::binary_oarchive`, `boost::archive::xml_oarchive`.

As long as your archive type itself doesn't vary, you can very easily use a Boost Variant to distinguish your payloads. In other words, make the serialization framework do the work for you, instead of "duct taping" around it:

Here's a demo that serializes 3 different (compound) payloads and roundtrips just fine without external knowledge of the payload actually there:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c15ba033b8a6df88)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>

struct A {
    int simple;

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar & simple;
    }
};

struct B {
    std::string text;

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar & text;
    }
};

struct C {
    A composed_a;
    B composed_b;

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar & composed_a & composed_b;
    }
};

struct FileContents { // conventions...
    boost::variant<A, B, C> payload;

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar & payload;
    }
};


#include <sstream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// For our roundtrip test, implement streaming as well so we can independently check equivalence
inline static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A const& v) {
    return os << "A{" << v.simple << "}";
}
inline static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, B const& v) {
    return os << "B{" << v.text << "}";
}
inline static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, C const& v) {
    return os << "C{" << v.composed_a << ", " << v.composed_b << "}";
}

void roundtrip_test(FileContents const& original) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
        oa << original;
    }

    {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);

        FileContents clone;
        ia >> clone;

        std::string const before = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(original.payload);
        std::string const after  = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(clone.payload);

        std::cout << "Roundtrip '" << before << "': " << std::boolalpha << (before == after) << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    roundtrip_test({ A { 42 } });
    roundtrip_test({ B { "Life The Universe And Everything" } });
    roundtrip_test({ C { {42}, { "Life The Universe And Everything" } } });
}
```

The output being:

```
Roundtrip 'A{42}': true
Roundtrip 'B{Life The Universe And Everything}': true
Roundtrip 'C{A{42}, B{Life The Universe And Everything}}': true
```

Comment: That is awesome. The FileContents struct is just what I missed. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have tried to implement this solution this morning, but I don't understand how to properly use boost::variant. I have created a base_project class that has boost::variant<local_uni_project, local_multi_project, regional_uni_project> for data member, but when I pass a local_uni_project to my serialization function (which takes a base_project object in input), there is a no-suitable conversion error.

Comment: I can only guess at your actual code. If these types are of related types (inheritance relation) there might be ambiguous conversions. _(Also, in such case, you clearly want to register the polymorphic types for serialization through a pointer-to-baseclass.)_. If not, can you show a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Meanwhile, here's with a simple example of how to _consume_ the variant after deserialization: look at [both `process_payload_switch` and `process_payload_visitor`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59d013806da401aa)

Comment: Thanks again @sehe I have tried tu use boost::variant in my project, but I found out that after including it, I face a System.IO.FileLoadException at runtime, saying that a dll or an assembly cannot be found. Are you aware of an incompatibility problem between boost::variant and some architectures ?

Comment: That has nothing to do with variant. You could easily have found that out yourself (http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/). Most likely the boost dlls are not in the directory where your mixed-mode dll is

Comment: I have a lot to learn about debugging. I have read the article and it is very useful. I have commented all lines of code that use boost::variant and program loads correctly. After uncommenting, FileLoadException is thrown. I added #include <boost\variant.hpp> and #include <boost\serialisation\variant.hpp> to the files that use variant, but problem persists.

Comment: You mean, you uncommented all code that uses boost serialization then... likely. You'll have to enable fusion logging or use DepencyWalker to find out what gives

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84095/discussion-between-dreamtool-and-sehe).